# Titan : Elastic Search Ignore stop word

Tags: titan

I am indexing country code as vertex property

```
v.setProperty("country","IN");
```

but when I do search like

```
g.indexQuery("search","v.country:IN").vertices();
```

It return zero result. I think its because of it hadling `IN` as stop word. How can I avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this by indexing country as a String:

```
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.Parameter
g.makeKey("country").dataType(String.class).indexed("search", Vertex.class,
    Parameter.of(Mapping.MAPPING_PREFIX, Mapping.STRING)).make()
g.commit()
```

See [Full Text and String Search](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Full-Text-and-String-Search) for further details.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: If i add `unique` `g.makeKey("countryCode").dataType(String.class).indexed("search",Vertex.class,Parameter.of(Mapping.MAPPING_PREFIX, Mapping.STRING)).unique().make();` it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A unique key must be indexed for vertices. Add 'indexed(Vertex.class)' to this key definition.`

Comment: That's expected, because uniqueness constraints are not supported for external index backends. If you add an additional Titan standard index, you can also use ```.unique()```.

Comment: How can make it possible that country code should be unique and also should not be ignored as stop word